# PHP cURL to return remote page stylesheets

Tags: php, string, curl

I'm using following code to get remote content using PHP cURL

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

This code returns whole content But I just want to print all stylsheets in following format.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/css/style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/css/style2.css">
```

How do I Filter content using str.replace() to only get stylsheets with cURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [simple html dom library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/),

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');
// or your can get $html string through your curl request and say
// $html = str_get_html($html);

// find all "link"
foreach($html->find('link') as $e) {
    if($e->type="text/css" && strpos($e->href, ":/") !=== false) // you don't want relative css hrefs. right?
    echo $e->href."<br>";
}
```

Comment: It might be interesting to know from where the `simple_html_dom.php` comes.

Answer (score 2):

If you **only** want to leave the `<link>` elements intact then you can use PHP's  `strip_tags()` function.

> **strip_tags** — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

It accepts an additional parameter that defines allowed tags, so all you have to do is set the only allowed tag to be the `<link>` tag.

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$linksOnly = strip_tags($ouput,'link');
```

The main problem here is that you don't really know what content you are going to get and trying to parse HTML content with anything other than a tool designed for that task may leave you with [grey hair and a nervious twitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) ;)

References -

- [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse the HTML tree and retrieve the required nodes - `<link>` in your case - and filter them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex:

```
preg_match_all('/rel="stylesheet" href="(.*)">/', $output, $matches);

if (isset($matches[1]) && count($matches[1]))
{
  foreach ($matches as $value)
  {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$value.'">';
  }
}
```

Comment: what if my site has `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/foo/" />`? I think the regex has a few caveats.

Comment: Well I can't agree more, but OP doesn't provide any output example. `href` can also be before the `rel`.

Comment: Which is why people say you shouldn't use a regular expression to parse HTML, I reckon ^_^ Ah well, it does answer the question, so +1.